# How do I delete items from a List<T> while enumerating the list using multiple threads?

Tags: c#, enumeration

I have an odd scenario in which I must enumerate a list on multiple threads, and the methods executing on those threads must be able to delete items from the list. Yes, I understand the design issues that reflects, but it's what I need to do.

I can't delete items as I go because that results in this exception:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

If this was single-threaded I would solve the problem like this:

```
for (var i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // depending on some condition:
    list.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

How could I solve this problem when multiple threads are enumerating the list?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194616/discussion-on-question-by-scott-hannen-how-do-i-delete-items-from-a-listt-whil).

Answer (score 3):

As stated, it would be better to solve this problem some other way, such as separating the list into separate lists. But for that weird, one-off scenario:

Instead of deleting items from the list as it's processed by multiple threads, mark them for deletion. Then, when all of the methods are done processing the list, create a new list out of the items that aren't marked for deletion.

One way to accomplish that without adding a property to an existing class is to create a new class and wrap instances of the existing class in the new one, like this:

```
public class Deletable<T>
{
    public Deletable(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public T Value { get; }

    public bool Delete { get; private set; }

    public void MarkForDeletion() => Delete = true;
}
```

Then you can use a few extensions to convert your `List<T>` into `IEnumerable<Deletable<T>>` and then filter out the "deleted" items when all of your threads are done:

```
public static class DeletableExtensions
{
    public static Deletable<T>[] AsDeleteable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source.Select(item => new Deletable<T>(item)).ToArray();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FilterDeleted<T>(this IEnumerable<Deletable<T>> source)
    {
        return source.Where(item => !item.Delete).Select(item => item.Value);
    }
}
```

Instead of passing `List<Foo>` to method, do this:

```
var deletables = fooList.AsDeleteable();
```

The result is a `Deletable<Foo>[]` which you can pass to other methods. It's not even a list, so those methods can't delete items from it. Instead they would call

```
item.MarkForDeletion();
```

When all of your threads are done processing, you would create a new, filtered result of the items that aren't deleted by calling:

```
var filtered = deletables.FilterDeleted();
```

---

This allows for the possibility that different threads are marking items for deletion for different reasons. In other words, they're not all doing exactly the same thing. If each thread is performing the exact same inspection then this should be handled using `Parallel.ForEach` or just breaking up the list into smaller lists. I can't imagine a scenario in which multiple threads should be doing the *same* thing with the same list.

Comment: Um, wouldn't enumerating _source_ in _FilterDeleted_  just create new Deletable<T> instances, and thus not filtering anything?

Comment: No, it's selecting `item.Value`, so in the example above the result is a new `IEnumerable<Foo>`.

Comment: Here another, slightly expanded, https://dotnetfiddle.net/XQiijO that explicitly shows all the instantiations of Deletable<T>'s.

Comment: I don't know how, but you're right. I'm suffering from a horrible case of code-blindness, because even though you're obviously right and it must be right in front of my eyes, I just can't see it.

Comment: The return value of _AsDeleteable_ is an enumerable based on a Linq query (`source.Select(item => new Deletable<T>(item))`). Whenever this enumerable is enumerated, that Linq query is being executed again upon the underlying collection to produce the enumerated items "on the fly". (It also means, every code/thread enumerating this enumerable will also work on their own, indidivually created Deletable<T> instances which will not exist for anyone else enumerating this enumerable)

Comment: That's what I get for posting without unit testing. It's fixed. Thank you.

Comment: While this is workable (using ToArray/ToList), i wonder whether it would be easier/simpler to just use a thread-safe collection type like `ConcurrentBag<T>`, perhaps, especially considering that with your approach threads will not "see" a deleted item disappear from the collection/enumerable and would thus be forced to filter by the _Delete_ property

Comment: I thought of that, which is why this is a weird one-off scenario. The real solution is not to have this problem. That's why I used a method to mark for deletion rather than a settable property. The implication is that multiple threads would mark items for deletion for different reasons and might inspect the same items. If the threads don't have different reasons for marking items as deleted then this should definitely be solved by breaking up the list or just using `Parallel.ForEach`.

Comment: Not downvoting or anything, but I thought one of the requirements was, *"the methods executing on those threads must be able to delete items from the list"*. If the method only marks it for deletion, then on subsequent iterations by any of the threads, the item that should have been deleted would still be there.

Comment: The OP wanted to delete items from the list, but the underyling intent was that they would end up a with a list that didn't have all of the original items in it. They can't delete items from the list, so this is a way to obtain the same result.

Comment: This solution relies on manipulating shared state from multiple threads without proper synchronization, in addition to not actually removing the items from the collection as requested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most reliable way to do this would be to use a collection type built for being operated on from multiple threads. The [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) namespace has several classes for this. While these classes support adding items from multiple threads, most do not allow you to remove a *specific* item from the collection; rather you can only `TryTake` the next available item.

However, the [`ConcurrentDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class *does* give you the ability to remove specific items, since they each have a unique `Key` that identifies the item.

If it's acceptable to move your collection into a dictionary (simply give each item in the collection a unique key when adding it), then here's an example of how it could be done, with 5 different threads each iterating over the entire collection, and each removing items based on a different (but in many cases competing) condition:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

private static void RemoveItems(Func<int, bool> condition)
{
    int temp;

    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        if (condition.Invoke(item.Value)) dict.TryRemove(item.Key, out temp);
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    // Start with a list of random integers ranging in value from 1 to 100
    var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => r.Next(1, 101)).ToList();

    // Add our items to a concurrent dictionary
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) dict.TryAdd(i, list[i]);

    // Start 5 tasks where each one removes items based on a
    // different (yet overlapping in many cases) condition
    var tasks = new[]
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RemoveItems(i => i % 15 == 0)),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RemoveItems(i => i % 10 == 0)),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RemoveItems(i => i % 5 == 0)),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RemoveItems(i => i % 3 == 0)),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RemoveItems(i => i % 2 == 0)),
    };

    // Wait for tasks
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);

    // Reassign our list to the remaining values
    list = dict.Values.ToList();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

Comment: The effort you've spent copying the list to a `ConcurrentDictionary`, and back to a `List`, all so you could parallelize the removal from the concurrent dictionary, is *twice* the work it would have taken you to simply serially removed the items from the original list.

Comment: Yes that's true, i added that in case changing the original collection type isn't an option. Then it really depends on what else the tasks are doing whether or not it makes sense to use this idea. parallel.foreach may also be a possibility here, the question lacks some detail on why they want to parallelize this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt for a direct solution to the problem, by making an enumerator than can be used concurrently by multiple threads, and allows removing elements from the list during the enumeration. Each element in the list is enumerated only once, so each thread processes only a subset of the list. I think that this arrangement complies better with the requirements of the question.

I couldn't make it with the standard enumerators because it is too risky to hold a lock from the call to `MoveNext` to the call of `Current`, so the enumerator is non-standard. It has a single method `MoveNext`, that also returns the current element as an `out` parameter. Actually it returns a wrapper of the current element, that includes a `Remove()` method that can be called to remove the element from the list.

```
public class ThreadSafeEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IList<T> _list;
    private readonly List<int> _indexes;
    private readonly object _locker = new object();
    private int _currentIndex;

    public ThreadSafeEnumerator(IList<T> list)
    {
        _list = list;
        _indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count).ToList();
        _currentIndex = list.Count;
    }

    public bool MoveNext(out Removable current)
    {
        current = default;
        T item;
        int i;
        lock (_locker)
        {
            _currentIndex--;
            i = _currentIndex;
            if (i < 0) return false;
            item = _list[i];
        }
        current = new Removable(item, () =>
        {
            lock (_locker)
            {
                var index = _indexes.BinarySearch(i);
                _indexes.RemoveAt(index);
                _list.RemoveAt(index);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    public struct Removable
    {
        public T Value { get; }
        private readonly Action _action;

        public Removable(T value, Action action)
        {
            Value = value;
            _action = action;
        }

        public void Remove() => _action();
    }
}
```

Usage example. A list of 10000 random numbers is processed in parallel by 4 threads, and all non-even numbers are removed.

```
Random random = new Random(0);
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(_ => random.Next(0, 10000)).ToList();
var enumerator = new ThreadSafeEnumerator<int>(list);
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(_ => Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext(out var current))
    {
        if (current.Value % 2 != 0) current.Remove();
    }
})).ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {list.Count}");
Console.WriteLine($"Top Ten: {String.Join(", ", list.OrderBy(n => n).Take(10))}");
```

Output:

> Count: 5020
>   Top Ten: 2, 2, 6, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12, 16, 18